# ultisnips with vundle

Tags: vim

Installed ultisnips successfully with vundle, but it wont load, none of the snippets work.

Here is a link to my vimrc https://bitbucket.org/panditaomesh/vimfiles/src/a542f92624b7/vimrc,

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: So it's not successfully installed, then. What doesn't work? What does? Does it work if you don't use Vundle? Do you have error messages? Does your Vim meets Ultisnips requirements? Does `:help ultisnips` work?

Comment: the snippet completions don't work. yes, my Vim meets Ultisnips requirements. Also :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes, :UltiSnipsEdit, :help ultisnips work.

Comment: found out the mistake had commented out the line filetype off before call to vundle. It is required by vundle to be off.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that people (and machines) will know that this question has been answered.

Comment: Please also see this link: https://answers.launchpad.net/ultisnips/+question/201789, especially my comment #2 which is yet another link. Vundle is quite picky in the way you have to configure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the mistake had commented out the line filetype off before call to vundle. It is required by vundle to be off.